# How to parse date time properly?

Tags: python, datetime

I'm having an issue parsing dates in python and I cant figure out what I'm doing wrong. I looked at a bunch of tutorials and I think I'm positively lost.

Here is what im trying to parse and the error that I am getting:
the code:

```
when = datetime.datetime.strptime(dateOfBirth, "+%Y-%m-%dT%I:%M:%S")
```

the error:

```
time data '+1909-04-01T00:00:00Z' does not match format '+%Y-%m-%dT%I:%M:%S'
```

Comment: Your datetime format doesn't expect a trailing `Z`.

Comment: And if you're allowing 00 as an hour, then you need `%H`, not `%I`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how it should be formatted:

```
when = datetime.datetime.strptime(dateOfBirth,'+%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ')
```

Comment: Use `%z` to parse the Z to UTC correctly. A literal Z just ignores it and you end up with naive datetime which is basically wrong because Python treats it as local time.

Answer (score 1):

This works, and keeps the timezone.

```
when = datetime.datetime.strptime(dateOfBirth, "+%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z")
```

Comment: You are right.  I (thought I) tried the %z  option in my experiments, but I must have done it wrong. I will amend.